# Default the value of an external key in a form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

In the form for adding a calendar (of the Model "Calendar"), in the "group" field shows a drop-down menu where all the "CalendarGroups" are. I would like this menu not to be there and "group" to be set by default with the "group" id which I pass through the url parameter ("group_id"). How could I solve this?

In models.py:

```
class CalendarGroups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 155, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
 
    @property
    def get_html_url(self):
        url = reverse('', args=(self.id,))
        return f'<a href="{url}"> {self.name} </a>'
 
 
class Calendar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    #created_by
    group = models.ForeignKey(CalendarGroups, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default='')
 
    @property
    def get_html_url(self):
        url = reverse('cal:calendar_view', args=(self.id, self.group))
        return f'<a href="{url}"> {self.name} </a>'
```

In forms.py:

```
class CalendarGroupsForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = CalendarGroups
 
    fields = ('name',)
 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CalendarGroupsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
 
 
class CalendarForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Calendar
 
    fields = ('name', 'group')
 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CalendarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In views.py:

```
def group(request, group_id=None):
    instance = CalendarGroups()
    if group_id:
        instance = get_object_or_404(CalendarGroups, pk=group_id)
    else:
        instance = CalendarGroups()
 
    form = CalendarGroupsForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cal:home'))
    return render(request, 'cal/form.html', {'form': form})
 
def calendar(request, group_id=None):
    instance = Calendar()
 
    form = CalendarForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cal:home'))
    return render(request, 'cal/form.html', {'form': form})
```

In urls.py:

```
url(r'^home/(?P<group_id>\d+)/calendar/new/$', views.calendar, name='calendar_new')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication), I solved it by modifying the code as follows:

In views.py:

```
def calendar(request, group_id=None):
    instance = Calendar()
  
    instance = Calendar(group_id=group_id)
    form = CalendarForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cal:home'))
    return render(request, 'cal/form.html', {'form': form})
```

In forms.py:

```
class CalendarForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Calendar

    fields = ('name',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CalendarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have send to the **views.calendar** the group_id key you need.
Now try to add it to the form before the form.save

Try to modify like this in view.py

```
def calendar(request, group_id):
instance = Calendar()

form = CalendarForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
if request.POST and form.is_valid():
    form.group=group_id
    form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cal:home'))
return render(request, 'cal/form.html', {'form': form})
```

Take note that might override what user can post on CalendarForm and you should consider to hide or make not editable that filed **group_id**,
Also this is slightly different to what i usually do but it should work
I Post also an example of what works for me:

```
def calendar(request, group_id):
instance = Calendar()
form = CalendarForm(request.POST or None)
if request.POST and form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.group = group_id
    instance.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cal:home'))
return render(request, 'cal/form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Ciao Alberto, grazie per la tua risposta! La tua soluzione non funzionava, purtroppo.. ma sono riuscito a risolvere il problema! Ho scritto la soluzione che ho trovato come risposta.